# how to preload tinymce editor?

Tags: user-interface, tinymce, jquery-ui-dialog, preloading

since tiny_mce takes long to load i tried preloading it's script and the image.. once i put the code below it won't load at all. can't figure out why.. paths are correct. if i remove this it will load slowly like before. and i am loading tiny_mce in a ui dialog. is anything conflicting? please help me...

```
$js = path+ "jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js";

                            $.getScript($js , function() {

                            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is that `tiny_mce.js` is not all you need in order to make tinymce work.
There are css files custom plugins and maybe other stuff that does not get loaded if you just load the js file. What you could do to improve speed is to download the tinymce developer version and then build your own tinymce_full.js using an ant build script.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. do u have any idea why tinymce is not loading when i use above code?(like i mentioned in my question)

Comment: because the tiny_mce.js file is just the basis to be able to initialize an editor. executing it does not create an editor instance. tinymce loads after you call an init function!! have a look here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration

Comment: i used above code to load it then some where else in the js file i call .dialog() function and inside it i initialize tinymce.